# SINTAXE INCORRETA VisuAlg

Tags: sintaxe, visualg, portugol

Preciso fazer um código para calcular o peso ideal de homens e mulheres, mas o professor disse que eu preciso fazer somente usando SE-ENTAO, e deixar o SENAO de fora, dai toda fez que eu executo esse programa o primeiro ESCREVAL depois do SE da erro de sintaxe `ESCREVAL ("Seu peso ideal é: ", peso_i)`, esse aqui, E
e tudo isso em portugol o que me buga mais ainda

Segue o meu codigo:

```
Algoritmo "peso_ideal"

Var
peso_i, altura: real

sexo: caractere

Inicio
TIMER (500)
ESCREVAL ("------------------------------------------------------------------")

ESCREVA ("Por favor informe seu sexo como F(feminino) e M (masculino): ")

LEIA (sexo)

ESCREVA ("Informe sua altura: ")

LEIA (altura)

     SE (sexo = "M") ou (sexo = "m")  ENTAO
        (peso_i) <- (450,7 * altura) / 10
        ESCREVAL ("Seu peso ideal é: ", peso_i)
        fimse
     SE (sexo = "F") ou (sexo = "f")  ENTAO
        (peso_i) <- (400,7 * altura) / 10
        ESCREVAL ("Seu peso ideal é: ", peso_i)
        fimse
     SE (sexo <> "F") ou (sexo <> "f") ou (sexo <> "M") ou (sexo <> "m") ENTAO
        ESCREVAL ("Por favor insira um sexo valido com F ou M")
        fimse

ESCREVAL ("------------------------------------------------------------------")

Fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

O separador de decimais é o ponto ("."), não a vírgula (",").

Não pode utilizar esses parênteses "()" nas variáveis ali no "lado esquerdo" da expressão.

De:

> `(peso_i) <- (450,7 * altura) / 10`

Para:

```
peso_i <- (450.7 * altura) / 10
```

###### ADENDO 1:

O VisualG é não é *case-sensitive*, logo, só precisa comparar de um modo.

De:

> `SE (sexo = "M") ou (sexo = "m")  ENTA`

Para:

```
SE (sexo = "M") ENTAO
```

Mas se quiser deixar, não tem problema...

###### ADENDO 2

O operador da expressão final seria "E", em vez de "OU".

De:

> `SE (sexo <> "F") ou (sexo <> "f") ou (sexo <> "M") ou (sexo <> "m") ENTAO`

Para:

```
SE (sexo <> "F") E (sexo <> "M") ENTAO
```

###### ADENDO 3

A verificação do sexo está fora do lugar...

Poderia ser algo assim:

```
INICIO
   TIMER 500

   ESCREVAL("------------------------------------------------------------------")
   ESCREVA ("Por favor informe seu sexo como F (feminino) e M (masculino): ")
   LEIA(sexo)

   SE (sexo <> "F") E (sexo <> "M") ENTAO
      ESCREVAL("Por favor, insira um sexo valido com F ou M")
   FIMSE

   SE (sexo = "F") OU (sexo = "M") ENTAO
      ESCREVA ("Informe sua altura: ")
      LEIA(altura)

      SE (sexo = "M") ENTAO
         peso_i <- (450.7 * altura) / 10
         ESCREVAL("Seu peso ideal é: ", peso_i)
      FIMSE

      SE (sexo = "F")   ENTAO
         peso_i <- (400.7 * altura) / 10
         ESCREVAL("Seu peso ideal é: ", peso_i)
      FIMSE

      SE (sexo <> "F") E (sexo <> "M") ENTAO
         ESCREVAL("Por favor insira um sexo valido com F ou M")
      FIMSE

      ESCREVAL("------------------------------------------------------------------")
   FIMSE
FIMALGORITMO
```

RESUMINDO: os erros não tinham qualquer relação com o não uso do SENAO.